# Stempel vs Siegel vs Paraphe

Tags: translation

I have been assigned to translate some german certificates and I observed that some of them (birth certificates for example) have **Siegel** written next to every institution's stamp while others (marriage certificates) don't display **Siegel**, which makes me wonder:

Does german make the difference between **Siegel**, **Stempel** and **Paraphe**?

When translating from english to german, would it be wrong to translate stamp as **Stempel** instead of **Siegel** or **Paraphe**?

Thanks for considering my questions.

Comment: German Wikipedia has separate articles on all three terms (modulo the a/e issue noted in my other comment) so the short answer is yes, they are different. I'm sure Wikipedia can fill in the details much better than I can.

Comment: @RDBury: One difference that may *not* become clear from Wikipedia is that "Stempel" and "Siegel" are both common words that virtually any native speaker will know (probably already as a child), whereas I had never heard of a "Paraphe" until reading this question.

Comment: @O. R. Mapper -- A nice feature of DWDS is it gives you a frequency rating on a word from 0 to 7. *Stempel* and *Siegel* are both 4/7 while *Paraphe* is 2/7. It seems to be a log base ten scale so 2/7 represents 1/100 the frequency of 4/7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A "Stempel" (not "Stampel") is a [(rubber) stamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_stamp) in general. The term doesn't signify what the stamp on the paper is showing.

A "Siegel" used to be a [seal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seal_(emblem)). A seal gets created with a "Petschaft" (signet), "Siegelring" (signet ring) or similar that's pressed into for example "Siegelwachs" (sealing wax). "Siegel" can also mean the symbol that's shown on the seal, like the [Great Seal of the United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Seal_of_the_United_States) or the [Bundessiegel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bundessiegel).

Today, people rarely use actual seals like described above, with wax and the whole nine yards. The seal (as in the symbol) mostly gets rubberstamped onto a document. So, you might say, there's a "Stempel" in somebody's office to put a "Siegel" on documents.

"Paraphe" is something else entirely. That term means a shortened form of a signature, like your initals. You might find it on a document with multiple or many pages, where one page gets *signed* and all the others get *initialed*.

Comment: Offenkundige Fehler in der Frage sollte man stillschweigend korrigieren. Mit Bezug auf die Frage vermindert man die Chancen auf Heilung der Frage, weil man dann mit der Heilung auch die Antworten entwertet, die jetzt Inhalt enthalten, der sich ohne Geschichtsforschung nicht mehr erschließt. Im Falle, dass man sich nicht sicher ist, sollte man in den Kommentaren nachfragen. Man verspielt so vielleicht die Chance der erste zu sein, der die Frage richtig beantwortet und die Aufwertungen aberntet, aber innerlich kann man sich das heimliche Goldpunkte für Disziplin gutschreiben. ;)

Comment: To clarify this: *Siegel* nowadays mostly represents a function, i. e. proving authenticity. This may well be be performed using a rubber stamp (not longer a convincing choice for first-glance verification in the age of 3D printers, but *Urkundenfälschung* of course is still a serious offence).

Comment: "The term doesn't signify what the stamp on the paper is showing." - I'm not sure this is correct, depending on what exactly is meant by this statement. "Stempel" refers to both the object that "prints" the graphic, as well as the graphic left by it on paper (or other materials).